# Do Unix-based Systems retain Daemons or Hardware Information post-Reboot?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, reboot, fan, daemon

**Background:**

I dual-boot Mac OSX Yosemite and Ubuntu 15.04 on a Macbook Pro Retina with rEFInd boot loader. I have a customized daemon for controlling the fans on Ubuntu, the reason being that I have always believed the "normal" control running in Ubuntu was too lazy and heated up way too much. Therefore, whenever my computer is slightly warm, it is almost all the way up. When I reboot my computer, I would assume that the Daemon for controlling the fans would shut down - after all, the computer rebooted. This doesn't appear to be the case, however - in rEFInd and in Mac OSX, the fans act exactly as if I had never left my Ubuntu OS.

**My Question:**

What on earth is going on? As far as I can tell, the Daemon should stop after being rebooted, as the OS that controls it turns off when I reboot the computer. Shouldn't a part of the EFI boot or the Mac OSX boot override the daemon?

This isn't a problem, it's mostly just wondering why on earth it happens.

Comment: I think the fans are controlled by the firmware, so the daemon of yours writes its setting into the nvram of the firmware, so the settings stay uless activly changed.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it continues with these settings post-reboot, as Mac should override it on boot.